# How to show alert/confirmation only on uncheck of check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a `asp:CheckBoxList` and I want to show a warning message  **only on uncheck** of check box  using jquery.

```
   $('.chklist').click(
     function () {
         if ($(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
             alert(this.id);
         }

     });
```

But the above code is always giving `true` even if item is checked or unchecked. As it is taking id for the whole list and not that particular check box. I don't want to implement the things on **post back event.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the click event handler on the input elements of the CheckBoxList, instead of the list itself. Assuming that the CheckBoxList has `CssClass="chklist"`:

```
$('.chklist input').click(function () {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert(this.id);
    }
});
```

It also works with your original code:

```
$('.chklist input').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
        alert(this.id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made a little sample of when the user deselects the checkbox.
Hope this is what you're looking for. Goodluck!

```js
$('#check').on('click', function(){
if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    // do something if the checkbox is NOT checked
    alert(this.id);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check<input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
```